# download a file from assets in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a sample file stored in the assets folder of my Angular App. I use the href link to directly save the file to desktop from the browser.

```
<a href="/assets/sample.csv" target="_self" download>
```

However, this works fine when the app is running on localhost:42xx server. But after using `ng build` and deploying it in an external domain it downloads the file but the file contains the html script of my app, where in reality the file present in the assets folder actually contains some random data. I have no clue why it works on localhost correctly but does not work on an external domain. Thanks in advance

Comment: `href="/assets/sample.csv"` is not pointing to correct path. Either provide full path aur adjust the path so that it will point to correct path after build . Directory structure gets changed after build command.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<a href="{{ url }}" target="_blank" >Trusted URL</a>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/cuxorawiju/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do it from controller, for example:

```
const path = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv";
window.open(path);
```